# как зациклить функцию в aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть такой код. Все работает, но мне нужно чтобы   `@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])` вызывалась не по команде `commands=['start']`, а зациклена. Пробовал вызвать `asyncio.run(scheduled(10))` Вот так:

```
# запускаем лонг поллинг
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(scheduled(10))
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True,)
```

Но тогда не работает `executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True,)` что я должен сделать что бы просто зациклить функцию `dp.loop.create_task(scheduled(10))` так же не работает, выдает ошибку `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_task'`

```
import config
import logging
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from sqlighter import SQLighter

from freesteam import FreeGame

# задаем уровень логов
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# инициализируем бота
bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# инициализируем соединение с БД
db = SQLighter('botgamebd.db')

# инициализируем парсер
fg = FreeGame()


# Команда активации подписки
@dp.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])
async def subscribe(message: types.Message):
    if (not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        # если юзера нет в базе, добавляем его
        db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id)
    else:
        # если он уже есть, то просто обновляем ему статус подписки
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, True)

    await message.answer(
        "Вы успешно подписались на рассылку!\nЖдите, скоро будут новые раздачи Игр и Софта, вы узнаете о них первыми =)")


# Команда отписки
@dp.message_handler(commands=['unsubscribe'])
async def unsubscribe(message: types.Message):
    if (not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        # если юзера нет в базе, добавляем его с неактивной подпиской (запоминаем)
        db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id, False)
        await message.answer("Вы итак не подписаны.")
    else:
        # если он уже есть, то просто обновляем ему статус подписки
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, False)
        await message.answer("Вы успешно отписаны от рассылки.")


# проверяем наличие новых игр и делаем рассылки
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def scheduled(self):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        game_info = fg.get_free_game()
        game_info.reverse()
        # получаем список подписчиков бота
        subscriptions = db.get_subscriptions()
        # получаем все игры
        for new_game in game_info:
            iterations = 3
            for game_id in new_game:
                if iterations >= 3:
                    if db.game_exists(int(game_id)):
                        iterations = iterations - 1
                    else:
                        db.add_game(new_game)
                        for s in subscriptions:
                            await bot.send_message(
                                s[1],
                                new_game
                            )
                        iterations = iterations - 1
                        continue
                else:
                    continue


# запускаем лонг поллинг
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True,)
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема в коде как раз во время вызова функции sheduled. Более поздних версиях aiogram нету метода loop, в классе dp. Вот фикс для вашей проблемы:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  loop.create_task(scheduled(10)) # поставим 10 секунд, в качестве теста
  executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```